# I am attempting to write my first "Hello World" code in Visual Studio 2013. Why am I received a "IntelliSense: no operator message" & "error C2563"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

```
#include <istream>  //Includes the input/output library

using namespace std; // Makes std features available
// The main function of the program 
// It outputs the greeting to the screen
int main()  {
    count <<"Hello World! I am C++ Program." <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
IntelliSense: no operator message Line 7, Column 8 
error C2563:mismatch in formal parameter list Line 7, Column 1
```

Comment: `<istream>` is not the input/output library. That would be `<iostream>`.

Comment: `std::cout` (no 'n') is defined in `iostream`, not `istream`.  Also, `using namespace std;` can potentially cause trouble, if you attempt to define a type or variable with a name that's also used by the standard library; you may find it hard to keep track of where you use yours, and where you use the standard one.

Comment: `using namespace std` is generally [not recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1848654).

Comment: It's `cout`, not `count`.

Answer (score 4):

**Replace `#include <istream>` with the correct header, `#include <iostream>`.**

- Helpful mnemonic:

  - `io` = input/output
  - `stream` = "stream of data"

**Additionally, the name of the standard output stream is `std::cout` or `cout` with the `std::` namespace scope removed.**

- Helpful mnemonic:

  - `std::` = Standard library's
  - `cout`  = console output

Answer (score 1):

The problems you are having with your simple block of code is simply: spelling errors.

**Firstly**, you have misspelled the input/output stream file in your *include* statement, so you need to rename the header file to:

```
    #include <iostream>
```

There is no heade file named *istream*.

**Secondly**, you also misspelled the *cout* function to *count*. Change that line to:

```
    cout << "Hello World! I am C++ Program." << endl;
```

Those lines should work now.

---

Also a recommendation for your future programs; avoid using the line

```
   using namespace std;
```

Why? Because as you move on to more complex programming, you will undoubtedly learn and begin to define a data type or variable, and sometimes, that name may also be used by the standard library. As a result, you will have a hard time trying to differentiate the variables or data types you defined and the ones defined in the std library.

Therefore, try and attach `std::` before every function that is a part of the standard library.

---

EDIT:
The code you posted in the comments box is pretty unreadable, so I just fixed it and have posted it below:

```
#include <iostream>  //Includes the input/output library

using namespace std; // Makes std features available

// The main function of the program 
// It outputs the greeting to the screen
int main()  
{
    cout <<"Hello World! I am C++ Program." <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried this in my IDE and fixed with the same and only recommendations from above. It works for me.

Comment: #include <iostream> //Includes the input/output library 

std:: // Makes std features available
// The main function of the program 
// It outputs the greeting to the screen
int: main(); {
  cout << "Hello World! I am C++ Program." << endl;
  return 0;
 }
Now I am receiving  a total of 6 errors that list these things:

Comment: Error 4 error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Comment: Error 1 error C2589: 'int' : illegal token on right side of '::'

Comment: Error 3 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: 6 IntelliSense: expected a declaration

Comment: 5 IntelliSense: expected an identifier